# Mongoose append to string while update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I try to append something to a string with findOneAndUpdate

My DB values

```js
{ _id: 'myId', name: 'Name', createdAt: ..... }
```

I try to append something to my name without doing two queries.

```js
await MongoModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: 'myId',
  },
  {
    'name': currentString + '_someString',
  }
)
```

and my output should look like

```js
{ _id: 'myId', name: 'Name_someString', createdAt: ..... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$concat` to concat current name and new string

```
await MongoModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: "myId" },
  [{
    $set: {
      name: {
        $concat: ["$name", "_someString"]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sw5ARsTK10r)